# org.hibernate.Hibernate constant for enum

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

my question very simple if org.hibernate.Hibernate.SRTING for handle String class, and org.hibernate.Hibernate.INTEGER for Integer class, so what constant in org.hibernate.Hibernate for handle enum class??

Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

Try

org.hibernate.Type.EnumType

Answer (score 0):

If your enum is non parametrized then just do this

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING) 
@Column(name="enumTest")
private YourEnum myEnum;
```

In case of parametrized a little bit trick is required see [here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Java5EnumUserType).